# filter html table based on a value by clicking a button using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

The code below creates a table from mysql on a web page. I want to be able to add 3 buttons and be able to filter the table information by male, female and show all using javascript/jquery. I have tried a few suggestions on stackoverflow but they don't seem to fit my requirement.

Please can someone help me with this on implementing a solution? :)

```
<thread>
    <tr>
        <th>Primary Key</th>
        <th>Full Name</th>
        <th>Gender</th>
        <th>Facebook Profile</th>
    <tr>
</thread>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" id="male">Male</button>
<br><br>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" id="female">Female</button>
```

```
echo "<br /><br />There are " . $num_rows . " participants.";

echo "<br />There are " . $num_rows1 . " male participants.";

echo "<br />There are " . $num_rows2 . " female participants.";

echo "<br /><br />";


while($tablev2=mysql_fetch_assoc($records)) {
   if($tablev2['gender']=='male') {
$var_tr = 'success';
}
elseif($tablev2['gender']=='female') {
    $var_tr = 'danger';
}

    echo "<tr class='$var_tr'>";

    echo "<td>".$tablev2['primary_key']."</td>";

    echo "<td>".$tablev2['name']."</td>";

    echo "<td>".$tablev2['gender']."</td>";

    echo "<td><a target = '_blank' href='".$tablev2['link']."'>Click to see their facebook profile</a></td>";

    echo "</tr>";
```

}

javascript:

$(document).ready(function() {

```
$("#male").click(function(){
    $('tr.female').toggle();
});


$('#female').click(function(){
    $('tr.male').toggle();
});
```

});

Comment: share the generated html and where are the buttons

Comment: you might want to try AJAX.

Comment: @ArunPJohny Here is the javascript and the buttons. For some reason, when I click on the male button to filter for information by male gender; it still displays info on people with no gender. Do you know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class names you are using are wrong, you are using the class names success and danger for male and female respectively.

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var filter;
    $("#male").click(function () {
        if (filter == 'male') {
            $('tr').show();
            filter = undefined;
        } else {
            $('tr:not(.success)').hide();
            $('tr.success').show();
            filter = 'male';
        }
    });
    $("#female").click(function () {
        if (filter == 'female') {
            $('tr').show();
            filter = undefined;
        } else {
            $('tr:not(.danger)').hide();
            $('tr.danger').show();
            filter = 'female';
        }
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/eodxv6du/)

---

If you can change the class names to male and female the it can be simplified to

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg filter" id="male">Male</button>
<br/>
<br/>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg filter" id="female">Female</button>
```

then

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var filter;
    $('.filter').click(function () {
        if (filter == this.id) {
            $('tr').show();
            filter = undefined;
        } else {
            $('tr:not(.' + this.id + ')').hide();
            $('tr.' + this.id).show();
            filter = this.id;
        }
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/eodxv6du/2/)

Comment: Thanks. I used the success and danger to incorporate bootstrap. I managed to use another method.

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution which doesn't remove the header row of the table with three buttons:

javascript:

$(document).ready(function() {

```
$("#male").click(function(){
    $('tbody > tr:not(.male)').toggle();
});

$('#female').click(function(){
    $('tbody > tr:not(.female)').toggle();
}); 

$('#all').click(function(){
     $('tbody > tr').show();
});
```

});